# How to create a reverse dictionary that takes in account repeated values?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to create a function that takes in a dictionary and returns a reverse of it while taking care of repeated values. That is, if the original dictionary would be

```
original_dict =  {'first': ['a'], 'second': ['b', 'c'], 'third': ['d'], 'fourth': ['d']}
```

the function should return

```
{'a': ['first'], 'b': ['second'], 'c': ['second'], 'd': ['third', 'fourth']}
```

I've written

```
def reversed_dict(d):
    new_dict = {}
    for keys,values in d.items():
        new_dict[values]=keys
```

but when I try it out with the original dictionary, I get an error "unhashable type: 'list'" when I try out the function. Are there any hints what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over the values in the list as well:

```py
def reversed_dict(d):
    new_dict = {}
    for keys,values in d.items():
        for val in values:
            new_dict.setdefault(val, []).append(keys)
   return new_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def reversed_dict(d):
    new_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for key, values in d.items():
        for value in values:
            new_dict[value].append(key)

    return new_dict
```

The problem with your approach is you're using the entire list as the key of the dictionary. Instead you need to iterate over the list (i.e. `for value in values:` in the code above.)

`defaultdict` just makes it simpler to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the values and add them as keys. You also have to take into account the possibility that you may have already added a value as a key.

```
def reversed_dict(d):
    new_dict = {}
    for keys,values in d.items():
        for v in values:
            if v in new_dict:
                new_dict[v].append(keys)
            else:
                new_dict[v] = [keys]
    return new_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because any of your `original_dict` values is a mutable type which is, as the error suggests, an unhashable type thus not
avalid candidate for a key in the `reversed_dict`.

You can workaround this problem by type-checking and casting mutable types into an immutable equivalent, e.g. a list into a tuple.

(also I find dict comp a way more elegant and concise approach):

```
def reversed_dict(d):
    return {v if not isinstance(v, list) else tuple(v): k for k, v in d.items()}
```